# Group by limit records in mysql workbatch

Tags: sql, database, mysql-workbench, mysql

i am use a mysql wokrbatch. i need result group wise limit of 2 records.
i have table like below:

```
|P_ID |Name     |Price | p_date             |
|1    |T-shirt  |500   | 2016-06-10 10:10:25|
|2    |T-shirt  |410   | 2016-06-10 10:10:27|
|3    |shirt    |450   | 2016-06-10 10:10:30|
|4    |T-shirt  |300   | 2016-06-10 10:10:30|
|5    |shirt    |500   | 2016-06-10 10:10:25|
|6    |pent     |600   | 2016-06-10 10:10:10|
```

and i want following result:

```
|Name     |Price | p_date             |
|shirt    |450   | 2016-06-10 10:10:30|
|shirt    |500   | 2016-06-10 10:10:25|
|T-shirt  |300   | 2016-06-10 10:10:30|
|T-shirt  |410   | 2016-06-10 10:10:27|
```

the result is base on group by name with descending order and have only
top 2 records

i have use the following query

```
select 
    name, price, p_date
from
    tempData.item_Master
where
    name in (select 
            name
        from
            tempData.item_Master
        group by name
        having count(name) > 1)
group by name , p_date
order by name , p_date DESC;
```

but it gives group by name result with all
records i need only two top records.

Comment: The general GROUP BY rule says:
If a GROUP BY clause is specified, each column reference in the SELECT list must either identify a grouping column or be the argument of a set function. (I.e. use max/min/avg on the price column.)

Answer (score 0):

You can do a group-wise limit with a correlated subquery, but not with `count()` and not with `group by`.  Here is one way:

```
select im.name, im.price, im.p_date
from tempData.item_Master im
where (select count(*)
       from tempData.item_Master im2
       where im2.name = im.name and
             im2.p_id <= im.p_id
      ) <= 2
order by name, p_date DESC;
```

Comment: this query is partially ok but it gives in appropriate result result conditions are: 1. select only those records who are appear more then one or we can say that those record which have abreast 2 entries in database table. 2. group by a result with name and p_date so we can get latest record and next to latest at the first and second position.
3. and finally take only first and second number from the result. here in your query it display all records. which is wrong in result pent will not be display

Comment: @jitenvaghela . . . I don't follow most of your comment, but this query should be returning only two rows per name.  That is how a correlated subquery works in this context.

Answer (score 0):

```
select  name, price, p_date
from   tempData.item_Master
where  name in 
 (select  name
  from   tempData.item_Master
    group by name
    having count(*) > 1)
order by name , p_date DESC;
```

and based on you last 2 comment  you can obtain the request 1 and 2 but not the 3 because if you want having  = 2 and group by p_date you can't get the 3 (see you sample)

```
select  name, price, p_date
from   tempData.item_Master
where  name in 
 (select  name
  from   tempData.item_Master
    group by name, p_date
    having count(*) = 2)
order by name , p_date DESC;
```